# Traversing nodes: Why check if node was included already?

Tags: javascript

In this breadth first traversal of a DOM, what is the purpose of `visitedNodes` array and how
does `!visitedNodes.includes(currentNode)` work?  What if I have 2 identical div's with the same class?  Wouldn't that check skip the 2nd div since it's identical?  That doesn't seem like ideal behavior, right?

```
function bfs() {

    const nodesToVisit = [];
    const visitedNodes = [];
    nodesToVisit.push(document.getElementsByClassName("a")[0]);
    const log = document.getElementById("results");

    while (nodesToVisit.length > 0) {
        let currentNode = nodesToVisit.pop(); // from the front!
        
        if (currentNode && !visitedNodes.includes(currentNode)) {
            visitedNodes.push(currentNode);
        
            if (currentNode.nodeType == 1) {
                let logItem = document.createElement("p");
                let logText = document.createTextNode(currentNode.className);
                logItem.appendChild(logText);
                log.appendChild(logItem);
            }
                [].slice.call(currentNode.childNodes).reverse()
                .forEach(function(node) {
                     nodesToVisit.push(node);
                })
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nuh-uh. `document.createElement('div') !== document.createElement('div')` Identical twins are not the same person, same goes for DOM nodes. So no, it won't skip the 2nd.

Comment: thanks!  I just noticed that in testing.  In what cases would they ever equal then?  I still don't know what the purpose of the `visitedNodes` array is.

Comment: `visitedNodes` is intended to avoid processing nodes that have already been seen in previous iterations. As @enhzflep points out, the equality will definitely fail since you are comparing two objects. To make this work, you might need to come up with a way to check for equality. For example, if two nodes have the same classes and/or, data attributes or something that checks for other properties for equality.

Comment: If I pop them of the stack though, shouldn't the possibility of seeing them again be non-existent?

Comment: You are right in this particular case since it begins with a single `nodesToVisit`, there is no way it or any of its descendant will be a descendant of themselves. My guess is that the author expected this loop could be called with more than a single `nodesToVisit` from the beginning, in which case it could meet the same nodes several times, e.g `const nodesToVisit = ...document.querySelectorAll("a")`